# textarea to mysql description dont work

Tags: mysql, textarea

I can't really see the problem in my code - I think it might be SQL query. I made a mistake with it but I can't really spot it out, it's my first time that I'm working with `textareas`.

So, if you have a good understanding of it, I'm really looking forward to your solution.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
?>
<?php include_once "includes/connection.php"; ?>
<h1>Outputting Games from the Database</h1>
<?php

// Connection to the Database


// Quering the database and outputting
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo $row['id'] . ' - ' . $row['name'] . ' - ' . $row['description'] . '<br />';

    }

}

// Insert the Data into the database
// Tjekker om formen er blevet sendt
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name']; // Ligger titlen i en php variable
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO menu(name, description) VALUES( {'$name' . '$description')}";

    // Vi laver et tjek om den er blevet indsat i databasen
    // Hvis der ikke skal være noget tjek kan du gøre lige som her:
    // mysql_query($sql);
    // bare slette denne if statement
    if (mysql_query($sql)) {
        header('location: insert.php');
    }

}

?>

<h1>Insert new game title</h1>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="name" />
<textarea name="description"></textarea>
<input type="Submit" value="Insert Game Title" />

</form>
```

The problem is that I can upload my input with the name of "name"
but i can't get my description to be includet.
basicly my query fails when i have :

```
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO menu(name, description) VALUES( {'$name' . '$description'} )";
```

in comparison to:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO menu(name) VALUES('$name')";

        if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name']; // Ligger titlen i en php variable
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO menu(name, description) VALUES( {'$name' . '$description'} )";

    // Vi laver et tjek om den er blevet indsat i databasen
    // Hvis der ikke skal være noget tjek kan du gøre lige som her:
    // mysql_query($sql);
    // bare slette denne if statement
    if (mysql_query($sql)) {
        header('location: insert.php');
    }

    }
```

If you can see a solution, you are very much welcome to help out.

Comment: Hi, this calls for basic debugging first and needs a more detailed description of the problem. What goes wrong where? What errors are you getting?

Comment: i dont really get any errors, my script runs but nothing happens to my DB...

Comment: Then the first step is debugging. What does `$_POST['description']` contain, is the "if" condition ever met at all...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have commented out the execution of your query:

```
// mysql_query($sql);
```

secondly: try changing the SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO menu(name, description) VALUES( '".$name."', '".$description."' )";
```

Try printing the SQL query to your page and see what it says.

```
print $sql."<br>";
```

Also print the mysql_error() if the query fails.

```
mysql_query($sql) or die ("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
```